# HTML video tag not working from server

Tags: html

I am trying to get a video onto a blank web page and figured the simplest way would be to create an `HTML` document and use that link. The server I am running this on is Windows 2008 R2 and runs IIS6.1. Unfortunately, it is not working on any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE11). I have combed through tutorials on YouTube, articles found on Google, on [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and the questions asked on here, Stackoverflow. Below is my code:

```
<video controls autoplay preload="auto">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg codecs='theora, vorbis'">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
```

I have also tried:

```
<object height="200" width="400" data="video.mp4"></object>
```

Also:

```
<iframe src="video.mp4"></iframe>
```

**Edit:**

After adding in the MIME types to IIS, it started to work on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. I still need this to work in IE.

Comment: what specific browsers have you tested this on that is not working?  Additional info please as well as a codepen or jsfiddle will be helpful.

Comment: I've tested them in IE11, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. Now it only does not work on IE11 since I added in the MIME types in IIS. I am going to update my question to reflect that and the new code I added.

Comment: so this works for external video URL's but not on video's running locally on your windows server?

Comment: If I send someone the link, it does not work if they are using IE11. On the local server or on my machine, IE11 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

use this and feed me back again if it not working if worked mark my answer as right answer

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YQHsXMglC9A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Please ensure that you have set dimensions for video tag and be sure that you have set the correct path of video like the following :-

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I want to use a video that is hosted on my server not from anywhere else. It does work with that but I need it to work with videos from my server. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

On the ISS, click Default Site. On right panel, There is MIME Types.. Open it. And click ADD link. Write ".mp4" to Filename Extension.. And write "video/mpeg" to MIME Type